# i am using log4net for logging purpose but it is not writing the logs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging

I have made changes into my Web.Config

I am using .net 4.0

I am using log4net i have added the reference

```
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>

<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Users\n.gupta\Desktop\CacheService.log"/>
    <appenToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <maxsixeRollBackups value="10"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="10Mb"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I have made changes in AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly:log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="Web.config",Watch=true)]
```

I have add the debugging into my controller

I have a shipment controller which contains a creating method in whihc i am logging

```
public class ShipmentController : BaseController
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = ogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ShipmentController));
    public ActionResult ShipmentCreation()
    {
        //I have attached the debug code for the message
        logger.Debug("Hello I am in Shipment creation Method");
    }
}
```

The file being created but it in not appending anything

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two syntax errors in your config's XML:

```
<appenToFile value="true" />
<rollingStyle value="Size"/>
<maxsixeRollBackups value="10"/>
```

`appendToFile` and `maxSize...` at the very least, must be corrected.